# Connecting a reliance zte AC2737 netconnect + modem

Tags: modem

I have a Reliance netconnect+ zte Ac2737. It has an allocated data of 5gb per month. The modem works fine only after the allocated data is over, for which i have to pay extra to the provider. I tried contacting the provider, but it was not of much help. The system detects the modem every time. I assume that it must be a possible problem with the provider, so is there any chance it is the problem of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit itself as i have no other reason to think otherwise an it works fine every time on windows.

Comment: are you using correct dialup number with modem? Try installing this software http://biggenius.org/modem-manager-gui-for-ubuntu/ And it will monitor data usage

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has no knowledge of how much data balance you have left, so the problem is indeed with your provider.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check these settings with your service provider like Reliance Card is CDMA or GSM.
If CDMA Card, number is different. You many need to enter your username and password too.